# Stored Procedure Parameters -> error converting data type nvarchar to money

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sqldatatypes

I am stuck with an error at my stored procedure. I've searched and tried different stuff, any solutions didn't fix it.

I want to check if the salary of employees are between two different values and that they don't cross the minimum or maximum value.

I use a trigger that fires on insert and update and gets the following data and uses that data to execute the stored procedure.

```
1 - job_id (INT datatype)
1000.00 - salaris (MONEY datatype)
13 - employee_id (INT datatype)
3000.00 - min_salary (MONEY datatype)
7000.00 - max_salary (MONEY datatype)
```

Calling of the stored procedure:

```
EXEC SP_Salary_Check salary, emp_id, job_number, min_salary, max_salary, '' (output)
```

Parameters of the stored procedure:

```
(@NEW_SALARY money , @EMP_ID integer, @JOB_NUMBER integer, @MIN_SALARY money, @MAX_SALARY money, @MSG varchar(50) OUTPUT)
```

If I insert an employee it will break on the parameters of the stored procedure. I will receive this error: **Error converting data type `nvarchar`to money**. Which indicated the attribute `@NEW_SALARY.`

If I change everything to `nvarchar` it works perfectly. If I only change the datatype money to `nvarchar` I will receive the same error but with integer instead of money.

Does anyone have a clue on this?

Insert statement:

```
USE [Outdoor_Paradise]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[employee]
           ([ss_number]
           ,[salary]
           ,[start_date]
           ,[termination_date]
           ,[first_name]
           ,[last_name]
           ,[work_phone]
           ,[extension]
           ,[fax]
           ,[email]
           ,[sales_branch_code]
           ,[job_number]
           ,[manager_id]
           ,[dept_id]
           ,[emp_details_id])
     VALUES
           (12345
           ,1500
           ,'2000-12-12'
           ,NULL
           ,'Foo'
           ,'Bar'
           ,'12345'
           ,'1000'
           ,'fax?'
           ,'foo@bar.nl'
           ,1
           ,1
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,1)
GO
```

Comment: can you please post an example of your insert statement.

Comment: Maybe you can consider using decimal datatype instead of money see https://sqlblog.org/2008/04/27/performance-storage-comparisons-money-vs-decimal

Comment: @Novice I added an insert statement.

Comment: @Bayeni I will get the same error.

Comment: You need to give us the sp code (and BTW never name a stored proc with the prefix sp - that is for system procs) so we can figure out waht is happening. Likely all the records in a table you are refernceing can;t convert to money.

Comment: post the code to your trigger and proc, can't help you without it.

Comment: You need to change the parameters and also the datatype in the table. The error explains you're trying to save data that is not compatible with the underlying datatype.